# How to scale form with font size in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, fonts

How can i scale a Form with font in WPF?

> i.e. What is the WPF equivalent of
>
> ```
> this.Font = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont;
> ```

---

In WinForms, if you're a good developer, you honor the user's font preferences. A WinForm that starts out as:

[image]

You then apply the user's font preferences:

```
this.Font = new Font("Segoe Print", 11, GraphicsUnit.Point);
```

and elements on the form ***scale*** to accommodate the new size:

[image]

Notice:

- the form is wider and taller
- the label is positioned further down, and to the right
- the label is wider and taller
- the text of the label is not cut off on the right or on the bottom edge
- the button is wider and taller
- but button is positioned further down, and to the right

> **Note**: In WinForms you can also use the line:
>
> ```
> this.Font = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont;
> ```
>
> WPF doesn't support `Font`, which is why i provided the clearer alternative. For the example below.

A similar WPF form starts out as:

[image]

You then apply the user's font preferences with:

```
        this.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe Print");
        this.FontSize = 14.666; //11pt = 14.66
```

and elements on the form *don't* scale to accommodate the new size:

[image]

Notice:

- the label's position has not changed
- the button's position has not changed
- the form is not wider or taller (text is cut off)
- the label is not any wider (text is cut off on the right)
- the label is not any taller (cutting off text along the bottom edge)
- the button is not any wider (text is cut off)

---

Here is another example of two buttons that are **the same size**:

**WinForms:**

[image]

**Windows Presentation Foundation:**

[image]

### Bonus Reading

- [WPF: How to specify units in Dialog Units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395195/wpf-how-to-specify-units-in-dialog-units)
- [How to prevent WPF from scaling with the Windows font size options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857098/how-to-prevent-wpf-from-scaling-with-the-windows-font-size-options)
- [WPF version of .ScaleControl?](http://WPF%20version%20of%20.ScaleControl?)

Answer (score 14):

WPF doesn't do primitive font-based scaling because it's... well, primitive. You can see it in your own screenshots.

Here's your "WinForms, before changing font" screenshot. Take a look at how much space there is between "sat on a log." and the right edge of the form.

[image]

And here's your "WinForms, after changing font" screenshot. Notice how much less margin you have after "scaling".

[image]

If you hadn't left all that extra space, then your label would be cut off with the new font. And with some fonts, it would be cut off even though you *did* leave all that extra space. That's what I mean when I say WinForms' scaling is "primitive". WinForms picks a single scale to apply to everything, and that scale is not chosen with any awareness of your content; it's based on *average* statistics for the font, which can and will fall apart once you start talking about specifics.

WPF doesn't hobble you with something that primitive. It gives you an amazingly powerful layout system, where it would be trivial to make a window that scales beautifully. But instead, you're choosing to cripple that layout system by using hard-coded sizes. **Stop it.**

Hard-coded sizes have two huge problems:

- They don't adapt to different fonts. You've noticed this already.
- They don't adapt to different content. (What happens when you want to make a German version of your app, and the German text doesn't fit into your hard-coded button size?)

Hard-coded sizes just *don't adapt.* To *anything.* You had to use them in WinForms because that's all WinForms supported. But WPF gives you a proper layout system, so you don't have to (and shouldn't) use anything that crude.

All you need is this:

- A `Window` with `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`. That way, the window will be exactly the right size to accommodate the text and button, no matter what font or language you use.
- Since you only have two UI elements, and one is above the other, you would put a `StackPanel` inside your `Window`.
- Inside the `StackPanel`, you need:

  - A `Label` or `TextBlock` to show your text, with the text in `Content` (`Label`) or `Text` (`TextBlock`); and
  - A `Button` with `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`, and the text in `Content`.
- Set some `Margin`s on the `StackPanel`, `TextBlock`, and `Button` to space things out to your liking.

That's it. Don't set any other properties on anything -- *especially* not `Width` or `Height`.

Now, if you change your font, the window and the button will still be exactly the right size, and won't cut off your text. If you localize your app into a different language, the window and the button will be exactly the right size, and won't cut off your text. Stop fighting WPF, and it will give you great results.

If you later want to make your layout more advanced, you could consider things like:

- If you want the button to be a little wider (to have more breathing room before and after the text), try playing with the `Padding`, or set a `MinWidth` and `MinHeight`. (Don't use `Width` or `Height` if your button contains text. You *might* consider using them if your button only contains an image, but maybe not even then.)
- If you're worried that the font might make the window so large that it no longer fits on the user's screen, and want to enable word-wrapping, then play around with `MaxWidth` and `TextWrapping`.

WPF's layout system is amazingly powerful. Learn it. Don't fight it by using hard-coded layouts and then complaining that your hard-coded layouts suck.