# How to scale WPF controls with windows font?

Tags: wpf

I am creating a personal project to get the hang of WPF and want to play around with its powerful layouts and options. Is it possible to scale my WPF form/window with the font size set in the windows settings? For example, a user can change their font sizes through the windows OS and I want my form to scale accordingly. How would I approach starting to set this up?

Edit: My original question is not phrased correctly. Essentially I am looking for an explanation on how WPF handles automatic scaling differently than winforms. Also I want to know how to set up automatic scaling from the beginning in a wpf form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scale form with font size in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556966/how-to-scale-form-with-font-size-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by setting the AutoScaleMode on your controls:

`this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi`

or

`this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font`

Not sure which will work best for the OS Font scaling (i am assuming DPI would be the choice, but i could be wrong).

Comment: Am I adding this line in my .cs constructor? Because I don't see a property called "AutoScaleMode" to even set it.